# Fails to configure snmpd with DTLS settings

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, dtls

Clean ubuntu 16.04
OpenSSL 1.0.2g
Downloaded net-snmp5.7.3 and ran ./configure to configure for TLSTCP,DTLSUDP

After generating and moving the necessary files (.crt, .csr and .key) according to [this tutorial](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_DTLS), I started editing *snmpd.conf* file. After editing, I restarted the snmpd service and checked the status. So the snmpd was running, but it reported errors and some warnings that it did not recognize the tokens:
[image]
So, it complains about the three lines I added to the `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` file at the beginning of the file (does it matter where those lines should go?):

```
24 [snmp] serverCert <fingerprint>
25 sertName 10 <fingerprint> --cn
26 rwuser -s tsm "username"
```

Any ideas what's the problem there?

Comment: Did you make and install, or only run configure? Did you specify --with-security-modules=tsm when you ran configure, or only --with-transports=TLSTCP,DTLSUDP?

Comment: @MichaelKirkham yes, I did. After `.configure` was finished, I could see the TLSTCP and DTLSUDP in the config table at the end. Then I did the `make` and `sudo make install`. After the installation I also needed to install the *snmpd*, *snmp* and *download mibs*, as they did not seem to be installed during the net-snmp installation (weird).

Comment: Perhaps they were installed to a different location than you were expecting? Your screen shot above shows /usr/sbin/snmpd, but default is probably /usr/local/sbin/snmpd.

Comment: @Nazar, did you found the fix for this?

Comment: @GunjanGupta I did manage to fix it, but I do not remember what it was, possibly a version of openssl. But I still had to abandon it because at that time the 5.73 snmp version did not properly support tls, I remember it was using SHA1, but pretended to use SHA2. Check the snmp 5.8 if is it out.

Comment: 5.8 is not out yet, But I did found my issue. I am going to post the cause of my issue here as the answer. If it was the cause of your issue as well, please feel free to mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and here is why this issue can occur.

In my case, I was using debian 9. As the snmp package on debian 9 doesn't comes with the tsm (dtlsudp) support, I downloaded the net-snmp package from its official site and tried compiling it. After I did make install, I too faced the same problem.

The reason for that was some of the libsnmp libraries from official debian's snmp packages was already installed in the system and the compiled snmpd was ending up using those libraries.

Check if snmp packages are already installed, by using

```
dpkg -l libsnmp*
dpkg -l snmp*
```

remove them from the system using

```
dpkg --purge --force-depends libsnmp* snmp*
```

Now install the compiled version using

```
make install
```